# How does one use phantom-dsl to connect DataStax Astra?

Tags: phantom-dsl

How does one use `phantom-dsl` to connect DataStax Astra? [Enhancement request #920](https://github.com/outworkers/phantom/issues/920) was created, but no movement on that. I am finding it too hard to find any information on how to leverage SSL alongside this driver. Any help is appreciated!